# Error trying to create a git bundle ranged between 2 commits

Tags: git, git-bundle

I am trying to create a bundle file from commit x to commit y.
As specified on [git bundle's documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) the arguments have to be  "*acceptable to git rev-parse and git rev-list ..., that specifies the specific objects and references to transport*" 
However, when I run the following command:

`git bundle create test.bundle 15b423..6cffeab`

I get the error

`error: Refusing to create empty bundle.`

Then I verified that the commits could be referenced by rev-list and rev-parse:

```
ana@DESKTOP-K400GGC MINGW64 ~/Projects/TEST1 ((20dc3fd...))
$ git rev-list 15b423b 6cffeab
6cffeabc7e3183fcca8cb8b91eecbf9e0af5a0e7
beb6fb7cfda467433cb2cdab362a25178b1ddf18
458cfcd0064b229f8b416d65405f18732d8c359a
53c90498e13edd32248842b3fd4fb7819041a1d6
ba087013804d4a39b36f3e679548fb45fe9645fb
ad1b1fde27be98b5b09d8e5a43137d16fd6e1840
540da9dea1b816a20be11e5c53b94467449266af
aa64d78ab5c990b047711b9f81fdae13beb27a05
15b423b91a63c403fe0ee0f3365c9846f37f3aa4

ana@DESKTOP-K400GGC MINGW64 ~/Projects/TEST1 ((20dc3fd...))
$ git rev-parse 15b423..6cffeab
6cffeabc7e3183fcca8cb8b91eecbf9e0af5a0e7
^15b423b91a63c403fe0ee0f3365c9846f37f3aa4
```

Why it doesn't work? How can I create a bundle file that ranges from commit **A** to commit **B** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From git bundle documentation (under Specifying References):
"git bundle will only package references that are shown by git show-ref: this includes heads, tags, and remote heads." So if you added tags to those commits, your command should work.

I do agree that the line that you quoted makes it seem like your command would work, IMHO that's not very clear.

Comment: Creating the tags worked, thanks! Although it creates repository with a detached HEAD.

Comment: And in general, the baseline can be a commit hash rather than a branchname. Only the target needs you to create some branchname first.

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the `git bundle` documentation is clearer, and include your usecase:

See [commit 1d9c8da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d9c8daef8d0c9c9f57e06eac7511c3b9355960b), [commit 0bb92f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0bb92f3a3a0034247868b4fcd901c18654b76c4d), [commit 9ab80dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ab80dd6aeadf398de45a6add5fc7ed6b2e166b7), [commit 5c8273d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c8273d57caf173517c9eb1ca77604709e2487b0) (31 Jul 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f19b275](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f19b2752e7788ad3a66812fd37fc482fc247eb4c), 24 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bundle doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0bb92f3a3a0034247868b4fcd901c18654b76c4d): elaborate on rev<->ref restriction
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Elaborate on the restriction that you cannot provide a revision that doesn't resolve to a reference in the "`SPECIFYING REFERENCES`" section with examples.

`git bundle` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0bb92f3a3a0034247868b4fcd901c18654b76c4d/Documentation/git-bundle.txt#L147-L184):

> Revisions must accompanied by reference names to be packaged in a
> bundle.
>
> More than one reference may be packaged, and more than one basis can
> be specified.  The objects packaged are those not contained in the
> union of the given bases.
>
> The 'git bundle create' command resolves the reference names for you
> using the same rules as `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref=loose`. Each
> basis can be specified explicitly (e.g. `^master~10`), or implicitly
> (e.g. `master~10..master`, `--since=10.days.ago master`).
>
> All of these simple cases are OK (assuming we have a "master" and
> "next" branch):
>
> ```sh
> ----------------
> $ git bundle create master.bundle master
> $ echo master | git bundle create master.bundle --stdin
> $ git bundle create master-and-next.bundle master next
> $ (echo master; echo next) | git bundle create master-and-next.bundle --stdin
> ----------------
> ```
>
> And so are these (and the same but omitted `--stdin` examples):
>
> ```sh
> ----------------
> $ git bundle create recent-master.bundle master~10..master
> $ git bundle create recent-updates.bundle master~10..master next~5..next
> ----------------
> ```
>
> A revision name or a range whose right-hand-side cannot be resolved to
> a reference is not accepted:
>
> ```sh
> ----------------
> $ git bundle create HEAD.bundle $(git rev-parse HEAD)
> fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.
> $ git bundle create master-yesterday.bundle master~10..master~5
> fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.
> ----------------
> ```