# Git diff and squashed email patches

Tags: git, squash

In certain scenarios git format-patch will not include merge commit or will generate patches in such a way that they cannnot be cleanly applied. In these scenarios I’d like to use git diff to generate a squashed patch in email/mbox format and also have it squash the commit messages into one so at least *some* history is preserved. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You say *certain scenarios*, but in fact, `git format-patch` will *never* format a merge commit, because it doesn't know how to do so.  It also won't format an empty patch (which may explain Git's relatively strong insistence on not making "empty", i.e., no-change, commits).  But, yes, if your commit range includes a merge (one or more, really), you are setting yourself up for trouble.

> In these scenarios I’d like to use git diff to generate a squashed patch in email/mbox format and also have it squash the commit messages into one so at least some history is preserved. Is there a convenient way to do this?

The short answer is no, because it's never obvious—at least in a mechanical sense—what to do here.

The best—at least, best built-in—way to preserve such commits and transmit them across a network gap that doesn't allow `git fetch` or `git push` is to turn them into a Git *bundle*.  A bundle is, in effect, *half* of a `git fetch` or `git push` operation.  You can send the bundle to another computer through any transmission mechanism you like, then, on the other computer, use `git fetch` to bring its commits into your repository at the other end.  See also [Why can't I git bundle all parents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51725375/1256452)

Failing that, you could attempt to use `git cherry-pick`, or the command that runs it for you, `git rebase` (probably in interactive mode), to turn your string of commits-including-merges into a more linear string of commits.  *Because* it's never obvious what to do around the merge points, you'll have to handle that yourself, some other way.  The resulting series of linear commits can then be fed to `git format-patch`.

If you're willing to turn everything into one single massive commit, you can just run `git diff` on the two endpoints (a starting commit and an ending one) and also run `git log` to gather up the log messages.  Formatting those into a mailbox-style message is pretty trivial.  Or, if you want, you can use `git commit-tree` to write a commit that uses the final tree but sets its parent to the starting point you like, then use `git format-patch` to format that single commit.  Since `git commit-tree` reads stdin for its commit message, you can use `git log`, perhaps with `--pretty=format:%B`, to gather up all the commit messages from the commits you're combining.

Comment: Yeah `git diff` is the way I'll need to go. Thanks for the tip at the end on how to bring three tools together to achieve what I want. I'll look into it.